# Facebook logout button (iOS SDK) proper segue upon logging out

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, fbsdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have ran into some trouble when using facebooks login framework. Logging in is fine, simple and works. My problem is when I click the FBSK logout button there is a verification (are you sure...) that pops up which stops me from using an action segue - what if the user says no, how can you ensure the segue runs only on confirmation?

So I am puzzled as to how to segue from one controller after the logout is successful because putting code in the `viewDidAppear` function doesn't work because the view isn't being refreshed, only the label changing from 'logout' to 'login'.

Update: Opted for `@IBAction` methods and used `FBSDKLoginManager.logOut()` to logout, however this removes the verification part and also opens the login pop-up straight away.

So I am still open to any suggestions.

Comment: There must be some delegate method to catch the `Yes` and `No` action of FBLogout button.

Comment: @TheRohanSanap There is a `loginButtonDidLogOut` method that I thought was supposed to be called when the button is pressed/user logs out, but in my case it never gets called. I am able to logout but to trigger the segue I put the code in the `viewDidAppear` method and then switch views, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The comment on your question is correct, get your view controller to conform to FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate and then control-click it to inspect the header file for your version of the SDK and what methods to implement.

Don't forget to tell your button its delegate is your view controller.

Comment: thanks @tenKinetic, my issue was i didn't conform to inspect the header file that's why it never invoke the didLogOut function.